# CodeIgniter : Unable to load the requested file:

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

Hi I’m just new in codeigniter. My website works locally, but when I uploaded it, I got this error:

An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: home\home_view.php

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class home extends CI_Controller{

function index(){

  $data=array();
  if($query=$this->home_model->get_dynamic_main_menu())
  {
  $data[‘main_menu’] = $query;
  }

  $this->load->view(‘home\home_view’,$data);
}


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: in my case folder's first letter was capital and in code I wrote small .. it worked on local but was not working in production

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try

```
$this->load->view('home/home_view',$data);
```

(and note the " ' " not the " ‘ " that you used)

Comment: oh - and one other idea - check the filename "home_view" is in lowercase - it might work on a windows machine, where it is case insensentive

Comment: still, I have the error. ` <?php $this->load->view('$main_content');?>
` in template.php and `$data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
  $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);` in login.php....?

Answer (score 10):

File names are case sensitive - please check your file name. it should be in same case in view folder

Comment: What if the file names are correct and still have the error.

Answer (score 2):

I error occor. When you are trying to access a file which is not in the director. Carefully check path in the view

```
 $this->load->view('path');
```

default root path of view function is **application/view** .

I had the same error. I was trying to access files like this

```
 $this->load->view('pages/view/file.php');
```

Actually I have the class Pages and function. I built the function with one argument to call the any files from the director **application/view/pages** . I was put the wrong path. The above path **pages/view/files** can be used when you are trying to access the controller. Not for the view. MVC gave a lot confusion. I had this problem. I just solve it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try
`$this->load->view('home/home_view',$data);`

instead of this:

`$this->load->view(‘home\home_view’,$data);`

Answer (score 1):

> "Unable to load the requested file"

Can be also caused by access permissions under linux , make sure you set the correct read permissions for the directory "views/home"

Comment: confirmed this is one possible cause :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in PyroCMS.

You can improve the error message in the Loader.php file that is in the code of the library.

Open the Loader.php file and find any calls to `show_error`. I replaced mine with the following:

`show_error(sprintf("Unable to load the requested file: \"%s\" with instance title of \"%s\"", $_ci_file, $_ci_data['_ci_vars']['options']['instance_title']));`

I was then able to see which file was causing the issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

> An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file:

Sometimes we face this error because the requested file doesn't exist in that directory.

Suppose we have a folder `home` in `views` directory and trying to load `home_view.php` file as:

```
$this->load->view('home/home_view', $data);// $data is array
```

If `home_view.php` file doesn't exist in `views/home` directory then it will raise an error.

> An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file:
>   home\home_view.php

So how to fix this error go to `views/home` and check the `home_view.php` file exist if not then create it.