# Unable to load the requested file in Php

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am working on Existing project (created by another developer)in Codeigniter,And i just want to load file(view), But i am getting following message

> Unable to load the requested file: test.php

Here is my controller function, where i am wrong?

```
$customer_id = $this->session->userdata('customer_id');
$customer = $this->site->getRowById('customer_information', 'customer_id', $customer_id);
if($customer->sales_active != 1){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('danger_msg', 'Sorry, You have not active !');
    redirect('customer/customer_dashboard');
}
$company_info = $this->site->getRowsByCondition('company_information');

$selectFields ='c.id as currency_id,c.img,c.decimal_curr, w.userid, w.id as wallet_id,w.updated_on, c.currency, w.address, w.balance,w.live_balance,w.usdt_price,w.total_usd,c.decimal_curr';
$where = array('c.status' => 1);
$where_in = array('w.userid',  $customer_id);
$orderBy = array('c.id','asc');

$joins = array('user_wallet w'=>'c.id = w.currency_id');
$getWallet =  $this->site->getleftJoinedTableData('currency_master c',$joins,$where,$selectFields,
'','','','','',$orderBy,'',$where_in)->result_array();

$new_currency = $this->site->customQuery("select * from bizzc_currency_master where status = 1 and id not in 
(select currency_id from bizzc_user_wallet where userid = '$customer_id')")->result_array();

// echo 'curr';die;
$data = array(
    'title' =>  'My Wallet',
    'customer' =>  objectToArray($customer),
    'customer_id' =>  $customer_id,
    'wallet' =>  $getWallet,
    'new_currency' =>  $new_currency,
    'company_info' =>  $company_info
);

$content = $this->parser->parse('website/customer/currency', $data, true);
$this->template->full_customer_html_view($content);
$this->load->view('test');
```

Comment: Did you create a file `test.php` in the `application/views` folder?

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648752/codeigniter-unable-to-load-the-requested-file